# Refreshing home launcher on home button press

Tags: android, launcher

I have a launcher application, which users can customise in different ways. But the changes do not reflect. I was thinking if i can detect a home button press and on that create my launcher activity again. But how do i achieve this?

Also, is there a better method for this?

Comment: If the changes aren't being reflected, that's a problem in your code.  Fix the problem instead.

Comment: What according to you will be the problem?  Also i do not have a refreshing method per se in my code, if there should be one, where should it be and what should it be?

Comment: How should we know?  We don't know what changes are being made, how they're made, what the structure of your code is.  You got a vague answer because you asked a vague question.

Comment: All changes are made through a single Settings Activity. Is there a way i can push my changes? Any way would suffice, i can build my own from that. I just need an example.

Comment: Sure-  write them to disk (such as shared preferences) and in the home activity read them from disk in onResume and put them into effect.  That's the easiest way to get it right.

Comment: Sorry, noob mistake. I was already doing all this, but in my `onCreate` method. Thank you, this is all i needed. Can you please write this as an answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: The life cycle gets us all once or twice when we're learning don't be too embarrassed about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the changes you want to make to the disk (such as `SharedPreference`) and reload them in the `onResume` function of your home screen activity.  Don't do it in `onCreate` or they will only be loaded once.